# What does 'read/write instant messages' do?

Tags: google, permissions, services

Here are my steps on a Motorola using Android 6.0.1
Go to Settings > Apps > Show System > Google Services Framework > Permissions > Additional permissions

What happens if I turn on these options?
- read instant messages
- write instant messages

[image]